# 15/8 blues playing live?

Tags: time-signatures, blues, live-sound, live

I am writing a bluesy piece. I tried a 15/8 and it works great. It sounds interesting but i don't think the band will be able to play it in that time signature. I was wondering if there is a good solution to play it 15/8 live. Any ideas?

Comment: It's going to depend entirely on how the melody line and/or rhytmic pattern is formed, could be as simple as 3 lots of 4/8 then a 3/8. Could be 3 lots of 5/8. If they can't manage 5 time, they'll never manage 15.

Comment: Gotta try 5/8 with the band

Comment: They may end up in 4 or 6! If so, you have an answer either way. But, yes, 5 is a lovely time sig to play in.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the idea of a blues with a non-standard time signature... would like a link to any recording of this!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqgyD_yTWCU

Comment: at what point does it not just become jazz with blues influence?

Comment: Rufus, an odd time signature doesn't make blues become jazz...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7KUYAwI-ig for an example in 11.

Comment: @topomorto Once I have it recording, if we manage to play it, I'll drop a link here.

Comment: @SovereignSun I'm intrigued.  What are the groupings? if it's 3+3+3+3+3 then it's probably easier just to think of it as a slow 5/4 shuffle; in the way something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNr_eIgP0tI can be thought of as as slow 4/4 shuffle or 12/8 depending on your perspective.

Comment: If you've written something in 15/8, and it works well, you should be able to play it to the band and just get them to copy the sound. How do you picture the drums sounding in your head?  When I show a new song, I often sort of beatbox a rough drum pattern to give the drummer a feel for what I'm picturing. Also, I am not a drummer, but for complex or unfamiliar timings I'll smack my hands on a desk in time, and sing the melody/guitar part/whatever so the band can hear how it all fits together. I don't play drums AT ALL, but if you know the groove of a song you should be able to do this.

Comment: Is there any chance of you posting a vocaroo or something of you just roughly outlining how your song idea sounds with just you and your guitar?  I'm really curious to hear a 15/8 blues...

Comment: @Some_Guy Actually, I play keyboard. Unfortunately, my band is paused for quire a time and we didn't even start playing it. However, I managed to save the main idea in Guitar Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's comment is great. I just wanted to add that 15/8 can also be understood as compound quintuple meter. As he pointed out it depends on the rhythmic structure of the melody and a complex time like this could be broken into several different smaller rhythmic groupings. If it turns out that the melody mostly fits into five pulses with triplet division then I would suggest practicing it as the meter I described above. If this is the case then it could be useful for your group to learn take five by the bruebeck quartet in order to solidify your familiarity with 5/4 time. It should be easier to do compound quintuple after getting good at simple quintuple and the swing of take five can justifiable give it a compound feel making for even better preparation. If you have questions about harmonizing or arranging this song for your groups instruments please feel free to contact me at strings.stringsandstrings@gmail.com or find me on Facebook as Guy Gastineau. I've arranged it for solo guitar and for a four piece. It's also a great song to have in the rep to play before breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The final arrangement will very much depend on the positioning of accents in the parts you have right now. As evidenced by the comments on your question, there's a number of ways to subdivide 15/8 time and the final choice will very much depend on which approach you will take.

There are several standard approaches, however, that I'd like to mention - as a jumping off point:

**The 5/4 shuffle**

Since it's a bluesy piece, the time signature suggests a triplet subdivision, possibly with a shuffle feel. If that is the case, the underlying rhythm can be viewed as 12/8 + 3/8 - essentially a four-beat shuffle (4/4 with triplet subdivision) with an extra beat tacked on the end.

**The 10/4 shuffle**

Essentially the same approach, but with a rhythm pattern that stretches for two bars of the basic time signature. It might alternatively be read as 12/8 + 12/8 + 6/8. The advantage of this approach is that the drummer can keep an alternating kick and snare every dotted quarter, which keeps the underlying beat easy enough to follow.

Depending on how the accents are distributed in the main parts, some hits may have to be moved around, but otherwise this would appear to *almost* be a standard even beat, so that the listener would really have to be paying attention to notice there's something strange going on. I consider this to be a benefit: overemphasis of the fact we're playing odd timings seems to me a cop-out.

**The truncated 16/8**

This even subdivision works out as 8/8 + 7/8 - two bars of 4/4, less an eighth note. It does require the band (especially the drummer) to be capable of playing 7/8 time.

**Straight 60/8**

This approach involves the rhythm section keeping a straight beat, extending over four bars of the underlying time signature. Again, accents may need some moving around, but this should feel more like syncopation than a non-standard time signature. It is equivalent to 7 bars of 4/4 (56/8) + 2/4 (4/8). As you can see, here - as in the 10/4 shuffle - the drummer can keep an alternating kick/snare pattern (this time falling on the quarter notes), whilst all the tricky compound stuff is happening over the top.

---

I've purposefully avoided more convoluted approaches, since you mention the band having trouble with compound time signatures. The 10/4 shuffle and straight 60/8 should be well within reach of just about any rhythm section.